# laravel (or core PHP) - Can I get a file from a server, without knowing the file ext?

Tags: php, file, laravel

I made a boo boo....

I built a system that let a user upload assets and track them.
Cool, it works.

I then used the same system to upload site specific assets (logos, employee headshots etc)... and then realized that as they're very static iamges, I don't need to use the asset system.

So now I've a folder on my storage server full of iamges labelled:

```
1_headshot.jpg
2_logo.png
```

etc

where the number is my employee database ref... what my issue is, is that I didn't track whta file type is uploaded...

My options:

1. Restrict users to only upload one file format
2. Use PHP to get a file regardless of the file ext...

No 1, I can do.. but I wonder.. is No 2 possible..??

I'm pulling from an S3 bucket if that's of any use?

Comment: Why do you want to keep this track? In order for the user to download it back?

Comment: If a user uploads a jpg as their iage, I need to know tro echo it as a jpg

Comment: Actually you shouldn't care about extension. You should care about mime type

Comment: Cool how can I get that from a file when I don't know the ext?
The answer below is perfect, but I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $filename = filename without extension ;
  $storage_path=storage_path();
  $files=File::glob($storage_path.'/'. $filename.'*');
  if($files) {
      $file=$files[0];
   }
```

`$file` will contain the filename with extension if it exists

Comment: This works great.. I had my issue in that I was letting users upload anything and that was the issue.. as I@m using 'intervention', I just saved the uploaded images in the required format.. but really appreciate the prompt reply!!